# Solving triangles with trig, word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Engineers want to measure the distance from *P* to *Q*, but the span from *P* to *Q* is across the tip of a lake. So they select a point *R* on land and find that the distance from *R* to *Q* is 100 feet and from *R* to *P* is 120 feet. Angle *QPR* measures 47 degrees. How far is it from *P* to *Q*?

So I started the problem by drawing a picture. I'm unsure if the angle *QPR* means the angle from *P*, but that's what I went with. I know the answer is 33.9049 feet by checking the answers in the textbook, but I don't know how they get there.

I first split the triangle down the middle to make it a right triangle. From there I did:

http://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP22271b87g8cab1h9d6ad000069452g2gc019030f?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=56&w=99.&h=32.

which gave me the height of the triangle, 87.76. I then used Pythagorean theorem to find that the length of the bottom leg of the right triangle is 81.84. Since that bottom leg is half of the required length, I multiplied by two and got 163.6, which is definitely not 33.9049.

Since that didn't work, I tried using law of cosines:

[image]

That got me nowhere since I was stuck with b^2

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that angle QPR is the angle at P.

Your first approach would only work if the triangle were isosceles.

What you have is a quadratic equation in the variable $b$ so you can use the quadratic formula to find the roots. Both roots are positive and one is the answer in your book. I don't see any reason why the other root couldn't be the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed two valid values $Q_1\approx 129.77469$ and $Q_2\approx 33.90491624$ that satisfy the quadratic equation,
see the picture for illustration:

[image]